# In deriving the expression for the position operator in momentum space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum

Consider this:
$$\langle \mathbf{r} | \hat{\mathbf{P}} | \psi \rangle = \displaystyle\int d^3\mathbf{r}'\displaystyle\int 
 d^3\mathbf{r}''\langle \mathbf{r}|\mathbf{r'}\rangle\langle\mathbf{r}'|\hat{\mathbf{P}}|\mathbf{r}''\rangle\langle\mathbf{r''}|\psi\rangle = \\ = \displaystyle\int d^3\mathbf{r}'\displaystyle\int 
 d^3\mathbf{r}''\langle \mathbf{r}|\mathbf{r'}\rangle\Big(-i\hbar\nabla_{\mathbf{r}'}\delta^3(\mathbf{r'}-\mathbf{r''})\Big)\psi(\mathbf{r''})
$$
Where $\hat{\mathbf{P}}$ is the momentum operator in three dimensions and $\langle\mathbf{r}|$ is the position bra.

Can I move the gradient to the outer integral?
I appreciate any tips on this.

Comment: Cool with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra–ket_notation#Spinless_position–space_wave_function)? Of course the gradient is acting on the delta.

Comment: Ok, that was a stupid question. But sending me the wikipedia page on braket notation isn't helpful.

Comment: Write out the δ function in r'-r, and collapse the r' integral . Pull out the gradient, now in r, and collapse the r'' δ function to get the gradient acting on ψ. The reason I sent you to that section of WP is because you see the answer by inspection there: that's where it basically came from. This looks like homework.

Comment: It ir homework, haha. Thank you for the answer. I'm having some trouble lately with these integrals that come from working in the x and p space. So my doubt, I think, was more about calculus than braket notation.

Comment: @CosmasZachos: I am not sure the gradient acts on the delta.

Comment: @fra_pero ? What do you mean? It doesn't or it shouldn't? It should, as per WP section linked.

Comment: The title suggest the OP is looking for $\langle p\vert\hat X\vert\psi\rangle$ whereas the actual question looks like momentum operator in position space.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if indeed calculus is your problem, I'll just remind you of the elementary calculus move, with one-dimensional integrals and $\delta(-x)=\delta(x)$ s,
$$
\int \!\! dy~dz~\delta(x-y) ~\partial_y \delta (y-z) ~\psi(z)\\
=\int \!\!   dz~ \partial_x \delta (x-z) ~\psi(z)= \partial_x \int  \!\!  dz~\delta (x-z) ~\psi(z)= \partial_x \psi(x).
$$

In bracket notation, this is self-evident by inspection from
$$
 \hat{\mathbf{P} }  =  \int\! d^3 \mathbf{r} ~~| \mathbf{r}\rangle (  - i \hbar \nabla) \langle \mathbf{r}| ~,
$$
so, in words, "enter the coordinate representation, take the gradient, and exit the coordinate representation". It's up to you, then, what else to do with the answer.